# VBScript issue after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, vbscript

So I have a VBScript that works together with VBA in excel and does the automatic update of the model every day (bound to Task scheduler). Besides saving the excel file with the current date in the name, it also save a hard copy in a pdf format(also with a relevant date). After switching to Win 10, every time the script runs, the window pops up and asks  - how would you like to open a file? Adobe, notepad, etc. pdf is by default opened by Adobe(set). So how can i get rid of that pop-up window? It defeats the whole purpose of automating the process and also prevents it from working properly, as after the pop-up, the pdf is not saved. 
Also, if I run the script through cscript via cmd, it all works fine, but if through task scheduler(also with cscript) than the problem persists. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taskscheduler has two modes to run tasks, one is using a specific account, the other is using the system account. Check which user runs the task, interactively logon with that user and make sure the standard program to be used with the .PDF extension is Adobe.
Is the system account is used, change this to a specific user because you won't be able to do this with the System account.
Try also running this task with the highest priority setting.

Comment: I messed around with task scheduler and realized, that actually it does not have a problem opening the pdf. Task scheduler does not know what exec to use to run vbscript straight. The only way I could come up with is to run wscript (or cscript) and input the script file as an argument. Win 7 knew how to run scripts..

Comment: it's the same thing as i explained with .PDF, you need to couple .VBS with cscript.exe while logged on with the user withc which your task is run